# How do I specify a relative db path for storing mongodb's data?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I'd like to use a relative path for mongodb, so that each user has a separate data directory when running mongo.

I've tried setting

```
dbpath = ~/mongodb_data
```

in my config file, but for some reason that doesn't seem to work - I'm getting:

```
ERROR: dbpath (~/mongodb_data) does not exist.
```

At first I thought it might be a permissions error, but I'm running mongod under a user that has rw to ~/mongodb_data.

Is what I'm trying to do feasible, and, if so, how do I get to doing it?

Comment: I believe cannot due to how `~` works, you must specify it from the root or from the directory itself like `mongodb_data`

Comment: How are you installing and starting MongoDB?

Answer (score 5):

Hello blueberryfields,

I was able to do that just like that on my windows machine:

```
mongod --dbpath ..\..\data\db
```

You can use a symbolic link as well.

But as already mentioned, a update on users start up script is the best manageable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the full path from root rather than using the tilde. I'm not sure it can use that.

```
dbpath = /home/yourusername/mongodb_data
```

Comment: That's not useful to me. I'd rather have a separate path for each user of the machine, and it would really suck if I have to use a separate config file for each user

Comment: You can set dbpath from the command line as well. Can you script to launch w/ the full user path on the command line rather than specifying in the config?

Comment: I often use a bash script to start Mongo with different dbpaths. Could you try passing the dbpath using a command line argument as suggested by James but put it inside a bash script so you don't have to type it out? The tilde might work inside there.

Answer (score 0):

As of MongoDB 6.x it is possible to use relative path as data and log directory (not with tilde). For the below configuration (as an example), if the server is started from bin directory, it uses the data directory and the logs in the mentioned log file.

This is useful in cases of automated installation of MongoDB from tar.gz file, where the installation directory is not known in advance and var directory may not be accessible. The only alternative to the below is to modify the config YAML post installation to include the path to the data directory and log file (I have used the below only as an example, data and log should be outside of installation directory but could be relative to it).

```
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: ../log/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: ../data
```